# Running a program with segmentation fault works well with gdb

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

I implemented the program that uses `mmap()` system call, but **Segmentation Fault** occurs during process runtime.

So, I ran this program with **gdb**, but when I did it, it worked well without segment fault.

I wonder if it is possible that running with gdb can affect segment fault.
Could you tell me about it?

Comment: which language? C/C++? whats the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if it is possible that running with gdb can affect segment fault.

One possibility: GDB disables address randomization (so as to make reproducing the bug easier). You can re-enable it with:

```
(gdb) set disable-randomization off
```

GDB may also affect timing of threads, but you didn't mention threads, so that's less likely.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably invoking Undefined Behavior somewhere in your code that is breaking C or C++ rules. Try to run the program under Valgrind. It should give you more information if this is the case.